# Passing data between components using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, components

I have a div like following.

```
<div className="horiz_center" onClick={this.textType.bind(this,'text')}>
   <img src={StarIcon} className="post_type_icon"/>
   <a className="post_type_text">Text</a>
</div>
```

I can get the value with this function

```
textType(postType) {

        this.setState({postType});

}
```

My question is if i want to use `postType` in another component, how can i pass it to that component?

Comment: You use `props` for that. Try to read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
const {postType} = this.state;
<MyComponent postType={postType} />
```

And in your component ( `MyComponent` ) access your properties like

```
this.props.postType
```